# Ouptut the current time using `datetime` to a file

Tags: shell-escape, datetime

How do I print the current time to a file using the `datetime` pacakge. While running `pdflatex` I am generating a `foo.def` in which I would like to add a comment at the top with the current date time in the `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format.

The following MWE works as desired if using the `datetime2` package (ie, the line `\def\UseOldDatetimePackage{}%` is commented) and yields:

[image]

in the pdf, the .log file and the `foo.def` file.

However, ir run as is, which uses the `datetime` pacakge, the pdf displays the correct result, but the .log file shows

> current time = \currenttime

and the `foo.def` shows:

> % \protect @day =\day \relax @month =\month \relax @year =\year
> \relax 2023/05/18 \protect \protect \c@HOUR =\currenthour \c@HOURXII
> =\c@HOUR \c@MINUTE =\currentminute \c@TOHOUR =\c@HOURXII \advance \c@TOHOUR by 1\relax @DT@modctr =\c@TOHOUR \relax \divide @DT@modctr
> by 12\relax \multiply @DT@modctr by 12\relax \advance \c@TOHOUR  by
> -@DT@modctr \c@TOMINUTE =\c@MINUTE \advance \c@TOMINUTE by -60\relax \multiply \c@TOMINUTE by -1\relax \c@SECOND =\currentsecond \relax
> 01:06:29\relax

So, what is the correct solution with `datetime`.

#### Note:

- Will eventually migrate to `datetime2`, but having some issue at the moment that I need more time to look into.
- The MWE requires the `-shell-escape` option to run.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\OldToday\today

\def\UseOldDatetimePackage{}% <-- Works if this is commented
\ifdefined\UseOldDatetimePackage
    \usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}
    \def\CurrentTime{\currenttime}%
\else
    \usepackage[]{datetime2}
    \def\CurrentTime{\DTMcurrenttime}
\fi


\def\TitleHeader{\today\space \CurrentTime}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\WriteFooTexFile}{%
    \immediate\write18{printf "\\n" > foo.def }% Initialize File
    \immediate\write18{%
        printf "\@percentchar s\string\\n"
            "\@percentchar\space\TitleHeader" >>
            foo.def }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \TitleHeader
    
    \typeout{current time = \CurrentTime}
    \WriteFooTexFile
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is hardcoding the format fine?

Comment: Sorry, but this won't work. `datetime` defines `\currenttime` as protected command (try `\ShowCommand\currenttime` to the this) using several other protected commands. So writing `\currenttime` to a file, (mostly) will and should indeed write `\currenttime` and not the expansion of `\currenttime` to the file. It cannot be expanded while writing to the file. You should use `datetime2`. BTW: I don't understand why you are using `\write18` to write to a file. Why not just open a file and write to it???

Comment: Maybe it would be better to ask questions about the issues using `datetime2` instead?

Comment: @cabohah: I don't remember the reason for using `write18` instead of `write`. I wrote my code to work with _both_ methods with an `\ifdefined` to switch between them and at one time I ran into an issue that seemed to only work with `write18` version and then just went with that.  Also, I will eventually switched to `datetime2`, but at the moment did not have time to determine the cause of a problem I have with using `datetime2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses the counters provided by `datetime` that store the current time but hardcodes the output format in an expandable manner:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\OldToday\today

\def\UseOldDatetimePackage{}% <-- Works if this is commented
\ifdefined\UseOldDatetimePackage
    \usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}
    \def\Today
      {\the\year\dateseparator\twodigit\month\dateseparator\twodigit\day}
    \def\CurrentTime
      {%
        \twodigit\currenthour\timeseparator
        \twodigit\currentminute\timeseparator
        \twodigit\currentsecond
      }
\else
    \usepackage[]{datetime2}
    \def\Today{\today}
    \def\CurrentTime{\DTMcurrenttime}
\fi


\def\TitleHeader{\Today\space \CurrentTime}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\WriteFooTexFile}{%
    \immediate\write18{printf "\\n" > foo.def }% Initialize File
    \immediate\write18{%
        printf "\@percentchar s\string\\n"
            "\@percentchar\space\TitleHeader" >>
            foo.def }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \TitleHeader
    
    \typeout{current time = \CurrentTime}
    \WriteFooTexFile
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to get the current time at the time `\CurrentTime` is called, not just the time at the start of compilation?

Comment: @PeterGrill I don't think the engines provide it, in LuaTeX you could most likely manage, but in pdfTeX and XeTeX things are a bit more complicated... You could calculate it with `\pdfcreationdate` and `\pdfelapsedtime`, but `\pdfresettime` would break this usage.

Comment: Tnanks for that suggestion. That should be sufficient.

Comment: @PeterGrill if you have `-shell-escape` as a hard requirement, it might be worth querying your OS for the current time instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution, that does not need shell-escape to write the current date and time to a file using PDFLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{iftex}
\makeatletter
\newwrite\foodef
\begingroup
  \def\@splitcreationdate #1:#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
    #2#3#4#5-#6#7-#8#9\@splithourminute
  }%
  \def\@splithourminute#1#2#3#4#5#6{ #1#2:#3#4:#5#6\@splitoffset}%
  \def\@splitoffset #1'#2'{#1:#2}%
  \immediate\openout\foodef \jobname.def
  \ifpdftex
    \immediate\write\foodef{\@percentchar\space
      \expandafter\@splitcreationdate\pdfcreationdate}
  \else
    \ifluatex
      \immediate\write\foodef{\@percentchar\space
        \expandafter\@splitcreationdate\pdffeedback creationdate }
    \fi
  \fi
  \immediate\closeout\foodef
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{\jobname.def}
\end{document}
```

writes, e.g.:

> `% 2023-05-18 11:29:06+02:00`

to the file `foo.def` (and reads `foo.def` afterwards, to also show this contents in the PDF).

Sorry, but I do not know, how to get the second using XeLaTeX.

Comment: This seems to work great.  Leaning towards accepting Skillmon's answer as that is pacakged better for my usecase.